# CSS divs don't align correctly

Tags: html, css

That's a simplified code where I have one absolute div with four relatives divs inside as four columns. Why the inside divs don't align with the top of the external div?

P.S.: I know there's other ways to make that but the real code is more complex and that's the kind of solution I need.

```html
<div style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px; width: 800px; height: 400px; background-color: red; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 25%; background-color: blue;">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
  </div><div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 25%; background-color: yellow;">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
  </div><div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 25%; background-color: green;">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
  </div><div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 25%; background-color: pink;">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because inline elements have their vertical alignment set to baseline by default. Change it to top:

```css
div > div {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px; width: 800px; height: 400px; background-color: red; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 25%; background-color: blue;">
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
        <p>3</p>
        <p>4</p>
    </div><div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 25%; background-color: yellow;">
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
    </div><div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 25%; background-color: green;">
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
        <p>3</p>
        <p>4</p>
        <p>5</p>
    </div><div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 25%; background-color: pink;">
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And if you want the parent container div to encompass the children divs, add `overflow:auto`.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli - However the parent is positioned absolutely. See what happens if you introduce a space between the child divs and leave the overflow out on the parent. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dpkvkqrm/

Comment: that is due to the container having a fixed height (*and of course breaking an already fragile layout - one based on `inline-block` elements with no whitespace*). It will not encompass them though, it will add scrollbars..

Comment: no real argument here.. i just think that last line is not relevant in this case..